# Are there entry requirements for layover airports between the USA and SE Asia?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

US citizens traveling from the USA to Ho Chi Minh City via Taipei, returning from Bangkok to the USA via Frankfurt.  Will not be leaving the airport in Taipei or Frankfurt.

What documents are required to pass through these airports?

(Documentation for the destination countries is understood, only asking about the layover airport countries.)

Comment: You will need your passport. And the boarding pass for your onward flight.

Comment: Watch out for the insane "need 3 months extra on your passport" nonsense. That can catch you out in any travel, these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very few countries around the world require a visa for transit for a US citizen.

Specifically for the two you've asked about, Taipei (Taiwan) and Frankfurt (Germany), US citizens do not even require a visa in order to enter the country, let alone to transit.

You will need to pass through security in both countries, but that is all.  You will not need any additional documentation other than what will be required for the trip in general (ie, a valid passport and a ticket to your destination)

Answer (score 4):

US citizens may visit [Taiwan](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-149-4486-7785a-2.html) for up to 90 days without a visa. Passports need to be valid during the entire visit.

US citizens may visit the Schengen States, of which [Germany](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/schengen-visa/963538) is part, for up to 90 days per 180-day period without a visa. Passports must remain valid for at least three months after departure; this rule also applies to airport transit.

Comment: Note that the Schengen States will introduce new rules in 2021 (exact date not decided). US citizens will in most situations need an electronic permit (ETIAS), before boarding a flight to the Schengen States, even if not leaving the airport.